# NDK UnsatisfiedLinkError when lowering project api level 21 to 19

Tags: android, android-ndk, serial-port, gradle-experimental

I made project using ndk with api level 21. But some reasons, I downgraded project api level 21 to 19.

My project worked fine in api 21, But after downgrading my project gives error in NDK part.

This is my error code when my project runs System.loadLibrary("serial_port");.

```
AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "tcgetattr" referenced by "libserial_port.so"...
AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:364)
AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
AndroidRuntime:     at com.josh.mainSelection.UartUI.onCreate(UartUI.java:220)
AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:811)
AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:627)
AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm first using NDK, and I'm not able to figure the problem.
please help me solving error.

I'm using gradle-experimental:0.4.0.

Comment: your `libserial_port.so` is missing some of it's dependencies, specifically `tcgetattr` symbol/method located in some other library... ? perhaps that's why the `dlopen()` call is failing (it's a C equivallent of System.loadLibrary() )
the problem seems to be related to [this function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tcgetattr) as shown by [this source dump](http://www.programering.com/a/MDO1MTNwATY.html)

Comment: Did you rebuild libserial_port.so with platform-19? The NDK platform level is defined separately from min or target SDK API level!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it works. But after deleting all .so files in my project and rebuilding, It works without any errors. I think .so files made in api level-21 made a crash someway.

Answer (score 3):

This made me crazy.

my `compileSdkVersion` `23`

But I solve it just now.

You can see the diff of `termios.h` file between API 19 and 21+.

so, I copy the `termios.h` from `D:\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\platforms\android-19\arch-arm\usr\include` to `jni` folder, and then it works.